# Not able to reach a computer on a bridged network with my LAN

Tags: home-networking, bridge

I had a linux old laptop with wifi and an old router, I decided to extend my wlan "X" to the second floor. I set the laptop in a sweet spot, connected to wlan "X" and used the linux ubuntu "Share connection" over Ethernet, connected the router to the the laptop's ethernet after turning off its dhcp.
Now I have wlan "Y" and connected ethernet-only devices to the old router (acting as a switch and wifi".
However, this lan "Y" has ip range of 10.42.0.X while my original lan "X" has ip of 192.168.1.X
Is it feasible to reach a computer from network "X" to network "Y" and vice versa?

Comment: A bridged network should have the same IP network across the LAN, since bridging is a layer-2 function and IP is a layer-3 function. Devices on the same LAN, but on different IP networks will not be able to communicate since you need a router to communicate from one IP network to another, but your router is only going to have one LAN interface which will only have one IP address in one of the networks, and it needs an interface and IP address in both networks to route between the networks.

Comment: can both internal adapters (wifi & ethernet) have IPs on the same network? whenever I choose "Share Connection" on gnome 3.x, the ip of the ethernet is forced to 10.42.0.1. I can't find any options to decide what ip should the ethernet have !!

Comment: I can't help you configure your PC, but I'm giving you the network perspective.